# Disable entity framework proxy creation and lazy loading from another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, lazy-loading

I have multiple projects referencing the a database project in the same solution and it all works great. I have recently added an mvc web api project to the collection and its retrieving data using the same business services.

I would like to disable lazy loading and proxy creation only in the instance of the web api. Is there a way i can do this global like in the application start in Gblobal asax.

XYZContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false
XYZContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating separate context for the API with settings initialized to required values

```
public class XYZContext : DbContext
{
}

public class XYZContextWithoutLazyLoadingAndProxies : XYZContext
{
    public XYZContextWithoutLazyLoadingAndProxies()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Or use configuration values from `web.config` in constructor

```
public class XYZContext : DbContext
{
    public XYZContext()
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LazyLoading"]?.ToString() == "false")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```